# unable to get samba to work in 17.04

Tags: samba

I have two computers (system1 and system19), each running 17.04.  I recently upgraded both at the same time from 16.10 to 17.04.  Under 16.10, samba worked perfectly between the two of them.  Now however, on 17.04, on each machine when I click on the "Windows Network" icon, instead of getting the workgroup icon that I can drill into in order to see icons for each of  the two computers, I instead get a blank window in Nautilus that says, "Folder is empty".

Here is my smb.conf file for system1 (system19's is the same):

```
[global]
workgroup = workgroup
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
dns proxy = no
preferred master = yes
domain master = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    server role = standalone server
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = yes
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
security = user
    guest ok = yes
guest account = main1

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
comment = Printer Drivers

[shared_stuff]
path = /home/main1/shared_stuff
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

When I run smbtree on system19 (itself), it shows only system19, and not system1.  But, when I run smbtree on system1, it shows only system19, and not itself (system1).  (Yes, I wrote that correctly - running smbtree on system1 shows only system19.)

At this point I am in over my head.

Question:  How do I determine what is wrong, why the two computers cannot "see" the workgroup (and each other)?  And, how do I fix the problem?

Thanks.